How to retrieve datas from an AuthorController class
I have created an AuteurController (AuthorController) class to retrieve database datas from Auteur table (Author table).
When i execute the program,

i can not retrieve anything(variable listAuteurs is null)
the local variables have the values below(joigned file) before executing  this instruction of the retrieve authors method( RecupLesAuteursAsync() )

var listAuteurs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Auteur>>(stringContenu);


I receive also the joigned error message  after executing the instruction above .
I must say that i made this AuteurController class since 5 years ago and i am a little "host".
With the code below can i retrieve values only if they are stored in a Collection(List) .
If i retrieve them from a database, i suppose i should use repositories as i did if AuteurController class is inside a Web api project(not MVC) as shown also  below. Can you confirm this.
Could you explain me what i need to do to retrieve datas from the table AUTEUR and display them as i need, using AuteurController class from a Asp.NET MVC project.
Thanks a lot to you because i turn around this subject since a long time...
Here is the AuteurController class code

using e_Bibliotheque.Models;
using Entite;
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace e_Bibliotheque.Controllers
{
     [RoutePrefix("/Auteur")]
    public class AuteurController : Controller
    {
        private const string urlAPI = "http://localhost:59281/";

        [Route("")]
        // GET: Auteur
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AfficherAuteurs()
        {
            VM_ListAuteurs modelAuteurs = new VM_ListAuteurs();
            
          modelAuteurs.ListAuteurs = null;
          
  try
            {
                
                modelAuteurs.ListAuteurs = await this.RecupLesAuteursAsync();
               
                return View(modelAuteurs);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("une erreur s'est produite" + ex.Message);

                return View(modelAuteurs);
            }
        }



public async Task<IEnumerable<Auteur>> RecupLesAuteursAsync()
{

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
         
        var objetReponse = await client.GetAsync($"{urlAPI}");


        if (objetReponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var objetContenu = objetReponse.Content;
            var stringContenu = await objetContenu.ReadAsStringAsync();

            **var listAuteurs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Auteur>>(stringContenu);**

           ** return listAuteurs;
**
        }
        else if (objetReponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {

            var objetContenu = objetReponse.Content;
            var stringContenu = await objetContenu.ReadAsStringAsync();

            throw new Exception("Un problème avec API : status = {objetReponse.StatusCode}, contenu : {stringContenu}");
        }

    }//fin de using


}//fin de methode RecupLesAuteursAsync()


enter image description here
enter image description here
namespace ServeurAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Auteur")]
    public class AuteurController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/AuteurAPI

       

        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]

        
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                IRepositoryAuteur repoAuteur = new RepositoryAuteur();
                var liste = repoAuteur.GetAll();
                

                if (liste?.Any()== true)
                {
                    
                    return Ok(liste);

                }
                else
                {
                    //Crée et retourne un System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult.

                    return NotFound();
                }



            }//fin  de try


            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //logger l'erreur

                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
   }

}


namespace e_Bibliotheque.Models
{
    public class VM_ListAuteurs
    {
        public IEnumerable<Auteur> ListAuteurs { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}

I tried to execute the AuteurController class code to retrieve Auteur table datas but i did not retrieve any datas .
I have difficulties to know if the code i propose can retrieve any datas correctly.
Thanks a lot again for your help
